# How to filter strings containing a specific pattern(file path)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to filter a white-space separated input string into a variable to contain file-paths under a certain directory, however it doesn't seem to work. I am expecting $(TEST_LIST) to be "usr/bin/test.bin", however it turns up blank...

What am I doing wrong?

```
TEST_LIST = $(filter usr/bin , usr/bin/test.bin etc/local/test1.bin etc/local/test2.bin)
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Vj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `$(filter usr/bin , ...` you will get only an exact match. That is, if `usr/bin` is in the list, you'll get that.

If you want to find `usr/bin` *follwed by something else,* you must add a '%':

```
TEST_LIST = $(filter usr/bin% , usr/bin/test.bin etc/local/test1.bin etc/local/test2.bin)
```

Comment: Oh I see.. but is there a wat to match on a substring? As in something like so: "%usr/bin%". I tried this.. it did not work..

Comment: @TheLoneJoker: That's not easy. (Weak wildcard-handling is one of Make's major shortcomings.) I'd probably define a function to test *one* path (using `subst` and `ifeq`), and return the path if it contains `usr/bin` and an empty string if it doesn't, then feed the list to the function by means of `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that make's functions that work on all words at once have limitations, you have much more you can do if you are working on one word at a time.

If you want to find all words in a list that contain a given substring anywhere in the word, you can use this:

```
IN := usr/bin/test.bin etc/local/test1.bin etc/local/test2.bin

OUT := $(foreach S,$(IN),$(if $(findstring usr/bin,$S),$S))
```